# Please help me of this Java printing order

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. I am confused about the java printing order. Please see my code:

```
public class Test {

private static int a;  
    private int b;

    static  
    {  
        Test.a=3;  
        System.out.println(a);  
        Test t=new Test();  
        t.f();  
        t.b=1000;  
        System.out.println(t.b);  
    }  

    static  
    {  
        Test.a=4;  
        System.out.println(a);  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {  
    }  

    static  
    {  
        Test.a=5;  
        System.out.println(a);  
    }  

    public void f()  
    {  
        System.out.println("hhahhahah");  
    } 
}
```

And the output is:

```
3
hhahhahah
1000
4
5
```

Could Anybody tell me why "hhahhahah" appears before the number 1000?
How does Java decide the printing order?

Comment: because you call `t.f();` before you print `System.out.println(t.b);` ?

Answer (score 0):

That's why you call `t.f()` before  `System.out.println(t.b);`

and `t.f()` prints `hhahhahah`

Answer (score 0):

Why it shouldn't be. Look at the order of your code

```
 Test t=new Test();  
        t.f();         //hhahhahah
        t.b=1000;  
        System.out.println(t.b);  //1000
```

You called a method (`f`) from class `Test` before printing the value of `b`.